# Pythonic way to calculate cumulative sum with complex math over numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, data-science, log-likelihood

I'm performing Data Science and am calculating the Log Likelihood of a Poisson Distribution of arrival times.

```py
def LogLikelihood(arrival_times, _lambda):
  """Calculate the likelihood that _lambda predicts the arrival_times well."""
  ll = 0
  for t in arrival_times:
    ll += -(_lambda) + t*np.log(_lambda) - np.log(factorial(t))
  return ll
```

Mathematically, the expression is on the last line:

[image: Text]

Is there a more pythonic way to perform this sum? Perhaps in one line?

Comment: You COULD write that using a  comprehension (`ll = sum(... for t in arrival_times)`), but it would take the same time and I'm not convinced it is more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems perfectly Pythonic to me; but since `numpy` is already here, why not to vectorize the whole thing?

```
return (
    -_lambda
    + arrival_times * np.log(_lambda)
    - np.log(np.vectorize(np.math.factorial)(arrival_times))
).sum()
```

Comment: Aha, I meant "vectorize" not "one line"! Something like this is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1):

If you have scipy available, use `loggamma` which is more robust than chaining `log` and `factorial`:

```
from scipy import special

def loglikeli(at,l):
    return (np.log(l)*at-l-special.loggamma(at+1)).sum()

### example 
rng = np.random.default_rng()
at = rng.integers(1,3,10).cumsum()
l = rng.uniform(0,1)

### check against OP's impementation
np.isclose(loglikeli(at,l),LogLikelihood(at,l))
# True
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer than mine

Answer (score 0):

This looks ugly to me but it fits a single line:

```
def LogLikelihood(arrival_times, _lambda):
    return np.cumsum(list(map(lambda t: -(_lambda) + t*np.log(_lambda) - np.log(factorial(t)),arrival_times)))[-1]
```